# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqf

Tags: react-native

I am getting following error while running the build command. However I am using only one version of google service.

```
:app:dexDebug
Unknown source file : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Unknown source file : com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzqf;
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {    
    compile(project(':react-native-google-signin')){
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile "com.airbnb.android:react-native-maps:0.7.1"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':RNMaterialKit')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `play-services:9.2.1` make sure you have same play-service version in your entire project including node modules.

Look at the following screenshot. I have same play-service version in the entire project.
[image]

**Solution**: Apply the dex in /android/app/build.gradle forcefully.

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'){
  force=true
}
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'){
  force=true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing node_modules is not the right approach, you can apply the dex in /android/app/build.gradle forcefully.

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'){
  force=true
}
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'){
  force=true
}
```

Do make sure that all your dependencies support 9.2.1